# Ansible and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, ansible, virtualenvwrapper

I have a deployment problem and I want to be able to use virtualevnwrapper in my host machines. But I didn't find any information according virtualenvwrapper. Just ansible modules for virtualenv.

Does the possibility of using virtualenvwrapper in ansible exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't need `virtualenvwrapper` as you can activate the `virtualenv` yourself. You need to source the `activate` file in the `<your_env>/bin/activate` directory prior to executing a `python` command with Ansible.

If the above doesn't work you can always adjust the `PATH` variable yourself to include `/path/to/my/virtualenv/bin` which is effectively what sourcing the activate file does. After that, it means the Python executable in that directory is used instead of the global one.

In other words, run a `python` command within Ansible with an updated `PATH` variable:

```
environment:
    PATH: /path/to/my/virtualenv/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}
```